# Login screen right frame is not showing site page

Tags: site.com, mydomain

In my org my domain is enabled and i have created visualforce page and added on site and that url i have passed in Authentication section. Clickjack setting is disable and site is active.

> Right Frame
> URL   https://force-ranger-dev-ed--c.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/MydomainPage

After that i have logout and trying to login page on right side breaking info showing

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the critical release that removes instance name from VF page domains?

Comment: no, i haven't removed

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of issues, mostly related to security settings on your site.

Here's an article I wrote recently that goes through all the steps involved to get to a working right-side frame page:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-by-step-instructions-hosting-setting-up-login-page-guy-clairbois